# Task<String> in Object Cache

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api

I am using this line of code to read previously saved Object from Cache

```
Task<string> responselist = cache["responselist"] as Task<string>;
```

Line used to save the object

```
cache.Set("responselist", response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), policy);
```

The reason I am using responselist variable as type Task because I return "Task" object in my method.

I am fairly new to Web API. I just want to know if it makes sense to this or there's better alternative?

PS: it works 100% fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use async/await keywords for it and store the primitive types in cache.

```
    public async Task Action(...)
    {
       string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       cache.Set("responselist", content, policy);

       /* ... */

       string content = cache["responselist"] as string;
     }
```

Storing the basic types/POCO classes is more natural than class like Task. By using the basic types you can save capacity in cache.